# Django : render the parent's data to the template only if the child of the child has data

Tags: django, python-3.x

this is my models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ordering_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering_num']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ordering_num = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['ordering_num']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class ProductBasicModels(models.Model):
    whose = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    standard = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    maker = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    outbox = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    extra = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    orderto = models.ForeignKey(OrderCompany, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
@ login_required
def product_list(request):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {'categories': categories}
    return render(request, 'medicalapp_1/products_h.html', context)
```

products_h.html
(simple structure...)

```
...
{% for category in categories %}
    {{ category.name }}
    {% for sub_category in category.subcategory_set.all %}
        {{ sub_category.name }}
        {% for list in sub_category.productbasicmodels_set.all %}
            {% if list.whose.id is request.user.id %}
            {{ list.name }}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
....
```

according to my code.. all of category and subcategory and products being displayed. But I want to make them display only products models has data.

like this..

```
category1
  subcategory1
    product1
    product2
    product3

category4
  subcategory1
    product4
    product5
  subcategory3
    product6
```

(category2,3) and (subcategory2 of category4) are not displayed because they don't have product..

How can I make filter in the view to work like it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make use of [regroup tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup). No need to fetch all categories in the `product_list()` method. Instead fetch all products (as the name intents) 
 - with `prefetch_related` to its foreign key(s), to optimise the query. Then `regroup` the queryset. That's all!

```
def product_list(request):
    products = ProductBasicModels.objects.all().prefetch_related('category','category__category')
    context = {'products': products}
    return render(request, 'medicalapp_1/products_h.html', context)
```

Then, in the template,

```
{% regroup products by category.category as cats %}
{% for cat in cats %}
    <br>{{cat.grouper}}
    {% regroup cat.list by category as subcats %}
    {% for subcat in subcats %}
        <br>{{subcat.grouper}}
        {% for product in subcat.list %}
            <br>{{product}}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**PS** :Two separate (& similar) models for category & sub-category *is **redundant** and you shouldn't be using it*. You may just use a single model with `ForeignKey` to `'self'`

Comment: great! it's perfact and very clean. and ill change the models according to ur advice. Thank you so much!

Comment: One more question.. What if I need to sort the display data by Subcategory?  How can I do in that view?

Comment: I've just found the filter solution and applied it. .order_by('category__ordering_num') Thank you!!